# TFS 2017 - Query-based suites can only contain test cases. So, add this clause: < Work Item Type | In Group | Microsoft.TestCaseCategory>

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have made query in a query based suite, and got the results as I hoped.

[image]

But when I try to "Save query" i get this error message:

> Query-based suites can only contain test cases. So, add this clause: < Work Item Type | In Group | Microsoft.TestCaseCategory>"

But as you can see I already got this clause in my query. 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid "OR" condition or group it somehow with other conditions.
Because currently there could be an item of any type with mentioned title, but it should be TestCaseCategory only

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why do I get the right tests when i "Run Query" but is not allowed to "save querry"? I thougt the querry was OK as long as I got the answers I was looking for in the querry?